# Trying to use Mysql with .net

Tags: .net, mysql, entity

I install the MySQL connector but this error

> "System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework
>   Data Provider.  It may not be installed."
>
> /// Initializes a new gerenteEntities object using the connection
>   string found in the 'gerenteEntities' section of the application
>   configuration file. Line 41:         ///  Line 42:
>   public gerenteEntities() : base("name=gerenteEntities",
>   "gerenteEntities") Line 43:         { Line 44:
>   this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

does not appear to show. I already added the references but it still does not work.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you add the DLL file as a reference?

Comment: YES... Mysql.Data and Mysql.Web

Comment: Do you have the MySQL Connector actually installed on your machine, or are you just using a reference to the DLL? I'm not sure if you **need** to install it, but that's how I've always done it.

Comment: Installation is not necessary. As long as you've referenced the right files, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is different to the direction you are heading in but recently I too had problems initalising a connection to MySQL. The solution I eventually found was to use the SharpSSH code written by Tamir Gal (albeit with slight modifications for my context) that you can get free. That might be worth looking in to if your problems continue.